# left and right regular representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I am working through representation theory and I have the following problem:

Show that left regular representation of a group $G$ on $\text{Fun}(G;F)$ is isomorphic to the right regular representation of $G$ on $\text{Fun}(G;F)$.

I'm clueless about how to begin. I'll be glad if someone can provide with any hints or references I'll figure out what to do.

Note: I have already proven right and regular representations are isomorphic to each other in normal case but this $\text{Fun}(G;F)$ is confusing to me.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "Note: I have already proven right and regular representations are isomorphic to each other in normal case..."   What is "normal case"?  What are "right and regular representations"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a finite group, then $\mathrm{Fun}(G, F)$, the set of all functions from $G$ to $F$, becomes an $F$-vector space in the usual way, by pointwise addition and scaling of functions. It also becomes a left representation by left translation: for $f: G \to F$ define $g \cdot f$ by
$$ (g_1 \cdot f)(g_2) = f(g_1^{-1} g_2)$$
and a right representation by right translation:
$$ (f \cdot g_1)(g_2) = f(g_2 g_1)$$

If $G$ is a finite group, it is easy to relate these representations to the group algebra $F[G]$ by considering the indicator functions $f_g: G \to F$, $f_g(g) = 1$ and $f_g(h) = 0$ for $g \neq h$.

Comment: It seems to me this misses the only essential point.  I think you point out that the left reg. rep. is the linearization of the action of G on itself by left translations, while the right reg. rep. is the linearization of the action of G on itself by right translations.  These two actions are actually isomorphic, and related to each other via the group inverse (which is the essential point).   Hence their linearizations are also isomorphic representations.   Finiteness of G plays no role.  Sorry to be critical -- I've seen other answers of yours that I admired.

Comment: @fredgoodman It's fine to be critical, and it's true that the finiteness of $G$ does not play a part here, but if $G$ is infinite, then the space of all functions $G \to F$ is not usually a useful space: it needs to be restricted to maps in whatever category is being considered (continuous maps, algebraic maps, etc). I interpreted the OP as being confused as to what the actions on the spaces $\mathrm{Fun}(G, F)$ were, not about how to proceed from there and show the isomorphism.

Comment: OK, thanks.  The left and right regular representations are defined by $L(g)(f)(g_1) = f(g^{-1} g_1)$  (as you wrote)  and   $R(g)(f)(g_1) = f(g_1 g)$  (no inverse).

Comment: @fredgoodman Thanks, I've fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\Fun{\operatorname{Fun}}$

Define $\alpha: \Fun(G; F) \to \Fun(G; F)$ by $\alpha(f)(g) = f(g^{-1})$. Then compute that $\alpha$ is a $G$-module isomorphism from the left regular representation to the right regular representation (and vice versa).